# insertbefore is working when I viewsource, but I don't see new dom element in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am inserting html before a specific element in a response to a ajax call.

I don't see the newly inserted html on the page, but if I do a view source I can see it.

I add the html in the success event of the $.ajax method call.

```
success: function(data) {
  $("#some-id").insertBefore(data);
```

}

It isn't hidden either, so not sure what is happening?

Comment: Some more code would be nice...

Comment: is `data` a selector to an element that's on the page? The syntax for `insertBefore()` is `$("content").insertBefore("target")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Expanding on my comment above)

Most likely, you want:

```
$("#some-id").before(data);
```

or:

```
$(data).insertBefore("#some-id");
```

Some more information from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/before):

> The .before() and .insertBefore()
>   methods perform the same task. The
>   major difference is in the
>   syntax-specifically, in the placement
>   of the content and target. With
>   .before(), the selector expression
>   preceding the method is the container
>   before which the content is inserted.
>   With .insertBefore(), on the other
>   hand, the content precedes the method,
>   either as a selector expression or as
>   markup created on the fly, and it is
>   inserted before the target container.

Comment: thanks, I had them mixed up. strange how the DOM looked fine though!

Answer (score 0):

If `#some-id` is not in your DOM by default and is being inserted dynamically, you'll need to append it before you can use `insertBefore()`